# Unable to deserialize JSON in c#

Tags: c#, json, rest, api, json-deserialization

I am getting the below JSON in response from a REST API.

```
{
   "data":{
      "id":123,
      "zoneid":"mydomain.com",
      "parent_id":null,
      "name":"jaz",
      "content":"172.1 6.15.235",
      "ttl":60,
      "priority":null,
      "type":"A",
      "regions":[
         "global"
      ],
      "system_record":false,
      "created_at":"2017-09-28T12:12:17Z",
      "updated_at":"2017-09-28T12:12:17Z"
   }
}
```

and trying to resolve using below code but that doesn't result in a correctly deserialized type.

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModel>(response);
```

below is a class according the field I received in JSON response.

```
 public class ResponseModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string zone_id { get; set; }
    public int parent_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
    public int ttl { get; set; }
    public int priority { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string[] regions { get; set; }
    public bool system_record { get; set; }
    public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
    public DateTime updated_at { get; set; }

}
```

What is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a wrapper class.

```
public class Wrapper 
{
   public ResponseModel data {get;set}
}
```

and then do:

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Wrapper>(response).data;
```

to get the instance of your ResponseModel out the `data` property.

You can deduct this from your json:

```
{ "data": 
   { "id":123, /*rest omitted */ }
}
```

The type that will receive this JSON needs to have a property named `data`. The suggested Wrapper class acts as that type.

Answer (score 2):

According to json2csharp website, your model seems to be incorrect. Try this one :

```
public class ResponseModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string zoneid { get; set; }
    public object parent_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
    public int ttl { get; set; }
    public object priority { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<string> regions { get; set; }
    public bool system_record { get; set; }
    public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
    public DateTime updated_at { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public ResponseModel data { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here a cool trick you can do in Visual Studio 2015-2017 where it generates the the correct class if you just copy the JSON (ctrl + c).

You need to create a new class in visual studio and once inside the class go to Edit menu -> Paste special -> paste JSON As Classes.

[Steps to generate json class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEvp4.png)

This will generate the C# object for that json for you and save you all the hassle :)

Comment: Very good trick. Did the same as json2csharp but in the IDE. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your model does not match your response - it matches the `data` property. Simply wrap another object round it

```
public class ResponseData
{
    public ResponseModel Data {get; set; {
}
```

and then

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseData>(response);
```